# Textbox.text does not show updated text in code

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

When I use the code below for some reason when Update is clicked, hospitaltextbox.text does not show the current value in the textbox? Just the value that was originally selected. Any idea why it is not reading what is currently in the textbox?

```
Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If (reader.Read()) Then

            HospitalTextBox.Text = reader(7)
            FirstNameTextBox.Text = reader(9)
            Session("ID") = reader(0)
        End If

Protected Sub cmdUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdUpdate.Click
    Dim Test As String
    Test = FirstNameTextBox.Text
    Try
        Dim Con As SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand
        Con = New SqlConnection
        Con.ConnectionString = ""
        Con.Open()
        cmd = New SqlCommand
        cmd.Connection = Con
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE tbltest SET [Teaching Hospital Name] = @TeachingHospitalName, [Physician First Name] = @FirstName WHERE ID = @ID"
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ID", (Session("ID"))))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@TeachingHospitalName", HospitalTextBox.Text)) 'does not show text that was changed in the textbox?
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@FirstName", Test))
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Con.Close()


    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: An empty `Catch` block is the root of all evil. Btw, instead of `FirstNameTextBox.Text = reader(9)` i recommend to use `FirstNameTextBox.Text = reader(reader.GetOrdinal("[Physician First Name]"))`. It's more readable and less error-prone.

Comment: Well in my page load function I have the select statement that sets the value originally ie HospitalTextBox.Text = reader(7)

Comment: That's your problem user1342164. see my note below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your `Page_Load` function.

Are you doing something on `PostBack` to set the textbox value to something else?

If you're binding data, make sure it's done when `Not IsPostback`

```
If Not IsPostBack
   BindData()
```

Comment: That was it I had to add If IS NOTPOSTBACK to my page load